# Building Java Programs

Tags: java, netbeans, build-process

So I have a directory of with a bunch of sub-directories that contain .java and .form files.  How do I build this program?  I'm sure that the program is build-able too, so I must be doing something wrong.

I'm used to writing C/C++ programs where I can just pass -I/path to gcc.

By the way, I'm using netbeans on an Ubuntu system.

Here's the output of tree:

```
.
|-- SimpleServerWithGUI
|-- SweepCollector
|   |-- Collector.form
|   |-- Collector.java
|   `-- sweepParser.java
|-- aGrapher
|-- basefunctionsModule
|   |-- basefunctionsModule.class
|   |-- basefunctionsModule.java
|   |-- getAction.class
|   `-- getAction.java
|-- n1996aModule
|   |-- Connection.class
|   |-- Connection.java
|   |-- N1996a.class
|   |-- N1996a.java
|   `-- n1996sweep.class
|-- newSquirrelSweepManager
|-- old
|-- squirrel
|   |-- Main.class
|   |-- Main.java
|   |-- actionList.class
|   |-- actionList.java
|   |-- commandparser.class
|   |-- commandparser.java
|   |-- squirrelAction.class
|   |-- squirrelAction.java
|   |-- squirrelLogger.class
|   |-- squirrelLogger.java
|   |-- squirrelModule.class
|   |-- squirrelModule.java
|   |-- variableList.class
|   `-- variableList.java
|-- squirrelClient
|   |-- squirrelConnection.java
|   `-- squirrelConnectionResult.java
|-- squirrelSweepManager
|   |-- BandView.form
|   |-- BandView.java
|   |-- DataAquisitionThread.java
|   |-- DataView.form
|   |-- DataView.java
|   |-- PresetView.form
|   |-- PresetView.java
|   |-- SweepManager.form
|   |-- SweepManager.java
|   |-- SweepManagerSimpleGUI.java
|   `-- sweep.txt
`-- squirrelSweepManagerDataModel
    |-- SweepBand.java
    |-- SweepData.java
    |-- SweepParameters.java
    |-- simpleSweep.java
    |-- sweep.java
    `-- sweepResult.java

11 directories, 45 files
```

SO now I'm at the point where I have a bunch of class files, like Main.class, how do I actually make an executable file?

Comment: The directory layout would be useful and any potential build files e.g. pom.xml or build.xml

Comment: there are no build files.  It's really just .java files and some .form files.  The directory structure, there is the root dir then several directories with the java and form files in it.  So it's one level deep

Comment: Did you create the project in Netbeans, and the source?

Comment: it's someone else's source, but I think the answer is yes.  I was told to use netbeans to build the project... I just have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any `pom.xml` or `build.xml` file in your project, your project is likely not using Maven nor Ant. So, unless you have a `.bat` (or .sh in your case) file somewhere, you'll have to rely on your IDE or to build the project by hand using `javac`, the java compiler (setting the required `CLASSPATH` manually).

Just for your information, the .form files are XML file that the Netbeans visual form editor uses to store information. You do not need to distribute them with your application; they are only used by the IDE. However, if you want to open your forms again in the form editor, you should keep the files.

Comment: So how do I configure netbeans to look in the right places for my other classes?

Comment: What other classes? What do you mean? I can't guess without more details on your project structure and what you've done so far. Can you paste the output of the `tree` command? Can you tell us what you've done under netbeans to setup your project?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to write an ant script, if the project doesnt have one (look for build.xml) 
Here is an quick tutorial on ant scripts ( read time like 15min ) with some examples, i guess it will have all that you need: 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1020-ant.html

Comment: awesome!  This is pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure should map onto the Java package names, so that the first java file `Collector.java` should belong to package `SweepCollector` and the file should be headed with:

```
package SweepCollector;
```

If you don't have this organisation it will be difficult to compile your code. You also have `n1996sweep.class` without a corresponding source file this might indicate something has got lost.